# MS Access Big File Size Problem with exported file from Python

Tags: python, vba, ms-access

I have MS Access File with a file size of 1.7GB. I have already tried to compact and repair, but the file size remains the same.

This is what I did. I download about 29 files from jupyter python to excel and csv files. The total amount of data is about 934MB.

I need to update the data everyday, therefore I linked the Access file to all the exported files under linked table and create another table to have a relationship with each other. So I have 2 tables for each exported file, for example: customer_linked and customer.

And this is the step by step of query:
1. Delete query for all data in non-linked table
2. Append query to append the linked-table to non-linked table

I have no idea that this way, it will make the file super bloated to 1.7GB. Is there any way to make it smaller?

Answer (score 1):

You can look into converting the excel files into csvs if you're looking to try and save space. Depending on how large the files are, there might be a lot of bloat in the excel files, full of extra stuff you don't need. If you're not using the excel files for images/graphs/formatting of some kind then you're best off just converting them all to csvs.

Comment: This is the weird thing I notice. I tried to export dataframe to csv and excel files. Surprisingly the file in csv take more space than the file in excel.

Comment: @BrianChew Then they are likely much bigger files. It doesn't make any sense that excel files with the same number of rows/columns as csvs would be smaller in size. If  you read both into Python as lists and count the total number of characters being stored in each cell for both files, then I expect you would find that the excel file is holding much less data.

Answer (score 0):

> Surprisingly the file in csv take more space than the file in excel.

No surprise if that is an *.xlsx* file, as these are *zip* files. Try renaming it to *.zip* and unpack it to see the real size.

If you have compacted it, that is the size - Nothing to worry about.

The only concern could be, that you are approaching the size limit of 2GB for an Access file. If that could hit you, consider moving data to, say, the free *SQL Server Express* edition which allows for 10GB.